# 24/7 Python selenium "while true:" script can't execute driver.get("URL")

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

This is an odd problem

My script has a `while True:` script running 24/7. It always hits `print ('False')` every `sleep(55)` seconds, and once the `current_time` is between specified times, it calls `driver.get("URL")` and does a few actions on a website.

But sometimes it hits an error where it cannot open `driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')` and prints the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/insta/users/nycforest/lcf.py", line 254, in <module>
    lcf_time(input_begin_time,input_end_time,input_begin_time2,input_end_time2)
  File "/home/matt/insta/users/nycforest/lcf.py", line 241, in lcf_time
    login()
  File "/home/matt/insta/users/nycforest/lcf.py", line 40, in login
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.70)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 5.4.0-1020-aws x86_64)
```

I tried adding `driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)` after `driver.get('URL')` but it hits the error above

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from datetime import datetime, time
from itertools import islice
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

input_begin_time = time(18,40)
input_end_time = time(18,50)
input_begin_time2 = time(21,20)
input_end_time2 = time(21,30)

opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument('--headless')
opts.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
opts.add_argument('--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess')



def login():
    sleep(2)
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
    sleep(3)

    input_username = driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
    input_password = driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)

    button_login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button')
    button_login.click()

# def other_functions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)

def lcf_time(time_begin1, time_end1, time_begin2, time_end2, curren_time=None):
    current_time = datetime.now().time()
    if time_begin1 < current_time < time_end1 or time_begin2 < current_time < time_end2:
        login()
        # other_functions()
        driver.close()
    else:
        print("False")


while True:
    lcf_time(input_begin_time,input_end_time,input_begin_time2,input_end_time2)
    sleep(55)
```

The odd thing is: I have a few different scripts running ***the exact same script with different variables*** and it some scripts are fine and others consistently hit this 60% of the time. I need a more reliable way to `driver.get("URL")` 24/7

Is this a compatibility issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that you're being rate-limited by Instagram?  They take a rather dim view of bots in general, so if you keep hitting their site from a script they might be periodically not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it with Selenium, you can do it with Python only or "**curl**" command.

In this way you can create a bash/shell script to trigger the script when you want and you won't need to keep the IDE running.

Comment: I have other functions other than `login()` that need to use Selenium's webdriver